# search for a line that contains unmatched delimiters

Tags: text-processing, latex

When running `pdflatex` and it crashes, my `.aux` file contains lines like

```
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {B
```

The only way I can think of to identify such lines is to count if the number of `{`'s exceeds the number of `}`'s in any line.    I want to be able to check the `.aux` file generated by `pdflatex` and determine if it contains such lines.
Is there a way to do this using `grep`, `awk` or some other utility?  Of course, if there's an alternative, more efficient way of identifying lines like these, I'd be delighted.

thanks for any advise

Comment: What sort of output would you like? You could print filename, line number, line (like `grep -Hn` does), possibly stopping at the first match. Or do you want an exit status indicating success/failure for a single input file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another brief one:

```
awk '{while(gsub(/{[^{}]*}/, "")){ }} /[{}]/ {exit 1}'
```

or maybe

```
awk '{x=$0;while(gsub(/{[^{}]*}/, "")){ }} /[{}]/ {print FILENAME,FNR,x;nextfile}'
```

This removes all balanced `{...}`, and takes some action if there is still a `{` or `}` character.

Comment: This was just what I needed.     just for completeness, I've put this line in my bash script   `cat myAux.aux | awk '{while(gsub(/{[^{}]*}/, "")){ }} /[{}]/ {exit 1}'` and now can condition on whether  `$?` is 0 or 1.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible (and very precise) in grep (with PCRE), but not simple to understand.

```
grep -Px '((?>[^{}]+|\{(?1)\})*)'
```

Or, defining the input (`$str`) and an appropriate regex (`$re`) we can do:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$str" | grep -vP "${re//[ $'\n']/}"
```

---

#### How that works?

Present day regexes could match balanced constructs (not most old regex engines).

In PCRE, recursion is the key to do that.

To [match a balanced set](https://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html#balanced) this structure is needed:

```
b(m|(?R))*e
```

Where `b` is the beginning pattern (`{` in your case),
`e` is the end pattern (`}` in your case),
and `m` is the middle pattern (something like `[^{}]+` in your case).

```
{([^{}]*+|(?R))*}
```

As could be [seen in action here](https://regex101.com/r/N8r0Pk/1).

But that is a non-anchored match that recurse the whole regex (`?R`).

An anchored version (to [match the whole line](https://regex101.com/r/cb6dpx/1)) could be obtained by using the `-x` option of grep.

A complete solution that allows for other text outside the braces becomes a bit complex, so, using an option of Perl regexes to ignore whitespace we can write. And changing the regex structure to (somewhat slower):

```
((m+|b(?1)e)*)
```

The original structure `b(m|(?R))*e`.

```
(?(DEFINE)(?'nonbrace'  [^{}\n]       ))  # Define a non-brace
(?(DEFINE)(?'begin'     {             ))  # Define the start text
(?(DEFINE)(?'end'       }             ))  # define the end text 
(?(DEFINE)(?'middle'    (?&nonbrace)  ))  # define the allowed text
                                          # inside the braces

(?(DEFINE)(?'nested'                            # define a nested
    ((?&begin)((?&middle)|(?&nested))*(?&end))  # pattern
  ))                                            # here

^((?&nonbrace)*+(?&nested))*+(?&nonbrace)*$     # finally, use this regex.
```

As [tested here](https://regex101.com/r/TAGXIs/1/).

Or the alternative structure  `((m+|b(?1)e)*)`

```
(?(DEFINE)(?'nonbrace'  [^{}\n]       ))  # Define a non-brace
(?(DEFINE)(?'begin'     \{            ))  # Define the start text
(?(DEFINE)(?'end'       \}            ))  # define the end text 
(?(DEFINE)(?'middle'    (?&nonbrace)  ))  # define the allowed text
                                          # inside the braces

(?(DEFINE)(?'nested'                             # define a nested
     (  (?&middle)++  |  (?&begin)(?&nested)(?&end)  )*
))

^(?&nested)$     # finally, use this regex.
```

as [tested here](https://regex101.com/r/nbcN3G/1)

Note that once the very long regex with many DEFINE gets compiled  by the regex engine it works at the same speed as a shorter one.

The added feature is that the description is clearer for humans (or, at least, I hope so).

That shows a clearer description of the regex, generally easier to understand to humans, but uses quite deep regex features from PCRE.

#### Script

To use all those ideas with grep (GNU and PCRE), use this shell (bash) example:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

str=$'
a
abc
{}
{a}
{{aa}}
{a{b}}
{a{bb}a}
{a{b{c}b}a}
n{a{}}nn{b{bb}}
\@writefile{toc}}}}{\\contentsline {section}{\\numberline {B
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\\numberline {B
Previous lines contain mismatched braces. This and the next line don\'t.
\@writefile{toc}{\\contentsline {section}{\\numberline {B}}}
'

re=$'                    
  (?(DEFINE)(?\'nonbrace\'  [^{}\\n]      ))
  (?(DEFINE)(?\'begin\'     {             ))
  (?(DEFINE)(?\'end\'       }             ))
  (?(DEFINE)(?\'middle\'    (?&nonbrace)  ))
  (?(DEFINE)(?\'nested\'
      ((?&begin)((?&middle)|(?&nested))*(?&end))
    ))
  ^((?&nonbrace)*(?&nested))*(?&nonbrace)*$
'

printf '%s\n' "$str" | grep -P "${re//[ $'\n']/}"

a
abc
{}
{a}
{{aa}}
{a{b}}
{a{bb}a}
{a{b{c}b}a}
n{a{}}nn{b{bb}}
Previous lines contain mismatched braces. This and the next line don't.
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {B}}}
```

#### Test results

And finally, to get all non-matching lines reverse the output with `-v` (source the script above if you need to execute what follows inside a running shell):

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$str" | grep -vP "${re//[ $'\n']/}"

\@writefile{toc}}}}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {B
\@writefile{toc}{ntentsline {section}{\numberline {B
```

Comment: Or just `grep -Pvx '((?:[^{}]++|\{(?1)\})*+)'`

Comment: Thanks @StéphaneChazelas Alternative nested structure explained.

Answer (score 1):

A `sed` translation of @rowboat's `awk` approach:

```
sed 'h; s/[^{}]//g; :1
     s/{}//g; t1
     /./!d; g'
```

That is:

```
sed '
  h; # save a copy of the line on the hold space
  s/[^{}]//g; # remove all characters but { and }
  :1
    s/{}//g; # remove the {}s (so starting with inner ones)
  # and loop until there's no more {} to remove
  t1

  /./!d; # if the pattern space does not contain any single
         # character, that means all {} were matched. Delete

  g; # otherwise retrieve the saved copy which will be printed
     # at the end of the cycle'
```

That's POSIX, but like the `awk` one would be much slower than solutions using perl-like recursive regexps such as:

```
grep -Pvx '((?:[^{}]++|\{(?1)\})*+)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

- for every record, initialize sum to zero.
- start inspecting a line character by character.
- increment sum when just saw an opening brace , decrement sum when seen a closing brace.
- as soon as the sum dips below zero, STOP.
- upon reaching the end of for loop , either midway due to negative sum or normally, exit with a nonzero status if the sum was nonzero.
- NOTE: this approach is not the same as counting the braces . Here we stop processing as soon as the sum goes negative.

```
awk 'BEGIN { a["{"]=1;a["}"]=-1 }
{ for (s=i=0; i++<length();) if (0>(s += a[substr($0,i,1)])) break }
s {exit 1}' file
```

---

The same thing in `perl`

```
perl -lne '
  local(%h,$^R) = qw/{ 1 } -1/;
  /(?:(?:([{}])(?{$^R+=$h{$1}})|[^{}]+)(?(?{$^R<0})(?!)))+/g;
  exit 1 if $^R;
' file
```

Perl has  powerful regex features, it's almost as if it's a mini programming language of its own. Inside the regex, we are doing the looping, updating the sum, and monitoring when the sum dips below zero.